# WP7 Header Height

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any specific controls to create the header in windows phone 7 like its there in iPhone?

If I have to create it myself then what is the recommended height for the header for my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a new page in Visual Studio it comes with a "header" that includes the page title. Please do not add an iPhone header containing back and other buttons. For the back button the hardware back button is used. Other buttons belong on the app bar at the bottom of the screen, not at the top like on the iPhone.